# Infer generic from type intersection

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to infer the generic of a type intersection with typescript but not sure  why the compiler is not inferring the positional argument correctly. For example:

```
type Brand<T, Y> = T & { __brand: Y}

type Foo = Brand<number, 'Hello'>

type ExtractT<T> = T extends Brand<infer A, unknown> ? A : never

function test(a: ExtractT<Foo>) {

}

test(1)  <-- error
```

I would have expected that `ExtractT` could pull the `number` from the `Brand<number,>` definition.

Is there any way to get this to pull the `number` type from `Brand`?

Playground link: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQgTgQwHYBMA8AVANFAmgPigF4oMoAyKAbygH1aAjRVALjwF8BYAKB9EigAxAPbDisZuiQBXALYMIcHAHIAEhAA2G4cvw8+4aAFEAHsEQBjYBkyESZCGYioAzhOToAlkgBmiqACCONJIANZIwgDuSIQA-IFQbEgQAG6K+tw+IVaewkhQwBAuwAAUCGym5ghWNiLC+ACU1BlcvNyFxSUAjA1AA

Comment: As far as I know there's no way to distribute an arbitrary type operation over intersections (as per [microsoft/TypeScript#38039](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38039), and since `Foo extends Brand<Foo, unknown>` there's no principled way to tell the compiler that you don't want `Foo` to come out of that check.  Undoing an intersection isn't straightforward.  If `T` were a nonprimitive type you could use `Omit` or something; otherwise I suppose you could do something very clunky.  I will look into it but my guess is that any solution will be a fragile workaround.

Comment: Okay, look at [this](https://tsplay.dev/WJ8pVN).  My suggestion here is to refactor your `Brand<T, Y>` definition so you can pull out `T`.  If it's really just for branding, there should be no trouble doing this (unless you can't touch the definition).  Otherwise, you can try doing things like in my other code, but it's super fragile; you need to anticipate possible `T` that don't work with `Omit`.  Let me know if this all makes sense to you and I can write up an answer.  Otherwise, let me know what I'm missing. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also faced the same problem. From this comment ([Infer generic from type intersection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68851634/infer-generic-from-type-intersection#comment121683945_68851634)) I realized that all we need is to save the type somewhere so that typescript can find it and output it later with infer. It's still not very convenient, but at least it works fine for me :)

```
type Brand<T, Y> = T & { __brand: Y, __T?: T }
// you dont even need to set the __T from the javascript side
// you can leave it undefined or uninitialized

type Foo = Brand<number, 'Hello'>

type ExtractT<T> = T extends Brand<infer A, unknown> ? A : never;

function test(a: ExtractT<Foo>) {

}

test(3)
```

Here is example of my problem and how I fixed it: https://tsplay.dev/w29YjW

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that `__brand` doesn't clash with any other objects, you can try...

```js
type ExtractT<T> = T extends { __brand: unknown } ? Omit<T, '__brand'> : never;
var x: ExtractT<Foo> = 1; // works
```